# How do I put two shaders on the same object separately?

Tags: modeling, shaders, color, toon-shading

I'm trying to make my character have blue jeans but peach feet, I can't find a way to separate it so that the leg contains both blue AND peach.As always, the .blend file is attached, but only 1 leg cuz 2 legs is 40 mb lol[image: the peach is what I want below that slight ridge on the leg.]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: no, I tried doing that but the faces don't line up with where I want. I could maybe line the faces up so that it doesn't put flesh tones on the pants? But if there's another way, I'd like to try that first.

Comment: Very short lived but I just made the leg and the pants separate objects. Thank you Emir for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to do it procedurally with the *Texture Coordinate* node and a *Mix Shader* or *Mix RGB* nodes (depending on whether you're mixing shaders or colours). Don't forget to change the Colour Ramp to be "constant" for a nice, sharp transition between the two (or more) textures.
[image: Node tree showing the use of generated texture coordinates feeding a mix shader]